# How to place picture in three d

Tags: asymptote

How do you add a 2 dimensional picture (an asymptote picture object) into a three dimensional drawing in asymptote? I have tried `add(picture, triple)`, but it gives no output (no errors, just a blank screen). 
Full code:

```
import three;
picture p;
size(p, 300);
defaultpen(0.1pt);
path P=polygon(6);
int h, k;
h=3;
k=5;
int bigger(int a, int b) {
    if(a >= b) {
        return a;
    }
    else {
        return b;
    }
}
real distance(pair a, pair b) {
    return sqrt((a.x-b.x)^2+(a.y-b.y)^2);
}
int bound = 1+bigger(h, k);
pair A=dir(60)+dir(0), B=dir(60)+dir(120);
for(int i = -bound; i<= bound; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j <= bound+5; ++j) {
        draw(p,shift((i*A.x, abs(i*A.y))+j*B)*P, blue);
    }
}
pair C, D;
C = h*A + k*B;
D = rotate(60, (0,0))*C;
clip(p,C--D--(0,0)--cycle);
draw(p,C--D--(0,0)--cycle, green+linewidth(0.15pt));
real Angle = aTan(C.y/C.x);
add(rotate(-Angle+180)*p, (0,0,0));
```

This (without including in 3d) produces this:[image]
I want to place it in three dimensions as the face of a solid, in the end producing something like this:

[image]

This may be an unreasonable request, but the reason I need this is because I have drawn a 2d picture as the "pattern" for each face of my 3d solid, and need a way to include it in three dimensions. The reason I had to draw it in 2d was because I needed the `clip` command, which is not available in 3d.

Comment: For clarity, please include a picture/screenshot of the desired output.

Comment: This can't be done easily, but there are two ways I can think of to approach it. First, you could use the `bsp` module -- see the picture `colorplanes.asy` in [the Asymptote gallery](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/). Second, you could implement your own clipping using intersections.